# iOS Simple View Pop from Navigation Stack Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

My storyboard looks like the following:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is when "Click Me" is pressed on the home page, to segue to "One" , check some logic on this controller, if successful, automatically segue to "Two".

Then when the "Back" button is pressed on "Two" it would take the user back home, essentially popping "One" off the stack.

Below is what my "One" controller looks like:

```
@implementation OneViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // example logic, in this case just force them to view two
    if(1 == 1)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        TwoViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}

@end
```

I'm getting strange behavior and receiving the following error:

> Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state.
>   Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.

I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've included the full dead simple source: http://andrewherrick.com/spike/pushpop.zip

**EDIT:**

I've tried moving the logic to ViewDidAppear and it simply kicks me back to the "Home" view automatically which isn't what I want.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    // example logic, in this case just force them to view two
    if(1 == 1)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];

        TwoViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey I donot have a complete knowledge of Stroyboard , but i did achieve this in View Based UINavigaitonController .if u want to know that i can help

Answer (score 0):

Putting your second push logic in `viewDidAppear:` rather than `viewDidLoad` solved the problem for me.

You should also consider the UX of your app. If a viewController is being used only for a few seconds to process some data and automatically segues into another viewController, it would be better practice to show a `UIActivityIndicator` or a small visual indicator.

EDIT:
Your automatic push should not pop itself before pushing another.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(1 == 1)
    {
        TwoViewController *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"two"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Then in your `TwoViewController` you need to programmatically call

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

in order to pop back to your Main viewController.

Comment: thanks for your help.. I've updated my answer above and it's not working. Was that what you had meant? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I also removed the line ```[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];``` When you are on the SecondViewController you need to create an IBOutlet for the 'back' button and have it execute this ```[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];```

Comment: Hmmm.. Ok neat.. So there is no way to do it whit out having to override the back button's default behavior on view two? I wasn't planning on necessarily calling the popToRootViewController method